# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: results is null or has length < 1

Tags: java, android

```
    btnCalculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Location.distanceBetween(lat1,lat2,
                    lon1,lon2, result);
            float[] result = {};
            textResult.setText("Ergebnis: " + result);
        }
```

I am currently trying to get the Location.distanceBetween to work. I get the Error

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: results is null or has length < 1

Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence of codes is wrong.

```
    float[] result = new float[1]; //need declare result array firstly
    Location.distanceBetween(latLon1.getLatitude(), latLon1.getLongitude(),
            latLon2.getLatitude(), latLon2.getLongitude(), result); //then get result
    textResult.setText("Ergebnis: " + String.valueOf(result[0]));//use result value
```

Answer (score 2):

Refactor your code like so -

```
btnCalculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            float[] result = {};
            Location.distanceBetween(lat1, lat2,
                    lon1, lon2, result);
            textResult.setText("Ergebnis: " + result);
        }
    }
```

From the documentation of `Location.distanceBetween()`,

> Computes the approximate distance in meters between two locations, and optionally the initial and final bearings of the shortest path between them. Distance and bearing are defined using the WGS84 ellipsoid.The computed distance is stored in results[0]. If results has length 2 or greater, the initial bearing is stored in results[1]. If results has length 3 or greater, the final bearing is stored in results[2].

Answer (score 2):

You need declare the array result before the Location.distanceBetween(...). And also you need give a space to the array like that:

```
float[] result = new float[1];

        Location.distanceBetween(10,10,5,5, result);

        textResult.setText("Ergebnis: " + result[0]);
```

This code shoulds work.